# Error when running SonarQube on TFS build

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I have setup a SonarQube 5.2 server following the PDF document "SonarQube Setup Guide For .NET users".
The server starts and I can access the website. I added the C#, TFVC, and msbuild runner plugins.

The server hosting the sources is TFS2015 and I have existing build definitions in XAML. When I try to start a build I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: tfsUri     
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.Integration.CoverageReportUrlProvider.GetCodeCoverageReportUrls(String tfsUri, String buildUri, ILogger logger)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.Integration.TfsLegacyCoverageReportProcessor.TryGetBinaryReportFile(AnalysisConfig config, TeamBuildSettings settings, ILogger logger, String& binaryFilePath)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.Integration.CoverageReportProcessorBase.ProcessCoverageReports()
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor.CoverageReportProcessor.ProcessCoverageReports()
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor.MSBuildPostProcessor.Execute(String[] args, AnalysisConfig config, TeamBuildSettings settings, ILogger logger)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception Message: TF270015: 'MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '255'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

I have seen that I need to define the collectionUri property. I have done so on the server web page in the SCM category under General Settings.

Any idea why the value cannot be found ?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Sergueï

Comment: Have you installed TFS 2015 Update 1? I think it's a requirement, though I can't remember where I read that

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we are using multiple build agents in our environment and the one I used for this test was still running Team Foundation Server 2013. Updating it solves the issue.
I am sorry for the useless post.